# Using seek() in Flowplayer with an FLV file

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, flowplayer

Is it possible to use Flowplayer (flowplayer.org) and the seek() function with an FLV file? I'm not streaming.

Answer (score 4):

You can call seek. But seek will only work inside the buffered length of the video. You can not seek to the point which is not buffered yet.

Answer (score 2):

To jump to a point 12 seconds into the movie I think it is.

```
$f("player").seek(12);
```

Were 'player' is the id of your player.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using pseudostreming plugin to do it: http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/pseudostreaming.html